# How do I fork an external process in java

Tags: java, process, operating-system, fork

I'm trying to fork a new external process (such as Calculator) in Java. I'm new to operating systems but I learned that it's possible using something like :
`Runtime.getRuntime ().exec ("C:\\Windows\\system32\\calc.exe");`. However that doesn't actually fork a new process. Is there anyway I can fork an external process using java?

Comment: In what way does that not start a new process? Windows doesn't generally `fork` anyway. Also, have you considered a `ProcessBuilder`?

Comment: I believe ProcessBuilder is what I'm looking for. I've searched on how to use ProcessBuilder but couldn't find a way to do it on a .exe file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you prefer a [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) over `Runtime.exec`. Also, if I understand your qestion, then you can pass the full path to the exe file to your `ProcessBuilder`. Something like,

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Windows\\system32\\calc.exe");
pb.inheritIO(); // <-- passes IO from forked process.
try {
    Process p = pb.start(); // <-- forkAndExec on Unix
    p.waitFor(); // <-- waits for the forked process to complete.
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```